# Highchart not resized when hidden

Tags: css, angularjs, highcharts

I've this AngularJS demo app using Highcharts:
http://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/dpw8b8vv/1/

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="myctrl">
        <button ng-click="hideView()">1. Hide</button>
        <button ng-click="showView()">2. Show</button>
        <div id="container" ng-show="show">
            <highchart id="chart1" config="highchartsNG"></highchart>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you change the width of the result view in JSFiddle, the Highchart will automatically resize it's width to the size of the container (the div with black border).

[image]

I've noticed that if Highchart is hidden, and the window is resized, it is not resized automatically (like iPad changing Landscape/Portrait orientation). Try this out by first clicing the "1. hide" button, change size of the result view, and then press the "2. show" button. See this example:

[image]

How can I force the highchart to resize even if it's not visible?

Comment: "Clicking hide..." -- have you got a JSFiddle with this functionality?

Comment: Sorry, wrong JSFiddle link. Post updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation, we need to trigger the `reflow` method in scenarios where resize event cannot be captured by the chart.

Triggering `reflow` method in `$timeout` will render the chart properly.

```
$scope.showView = function () {
        $scope.show = true;
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.highchartsNG.getHighcharts().reflow()
        });
    }
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpw8b8vv/2/)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a correct behaviour.

But considering that the resize event event fix the graph size, you can trigger a resize after the graph is shown, like:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
}, 1);
```

It's the jQuery way, I think there's an angular too, but I'm not familiar with it.